# Can anyone solve this python machine learning problem??? *ValueError: could not convert string to float*

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The project is about if you input a color of the lego piece (A) it will output if its translucent or not(B)
the data set has in the bottom has all of the data

Here's the error:ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bright Green'

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


data = pd.read_csv('colors_without_rgb.csv')


X = data.drop(columns=["is_trans"])
y = data['is_trans']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LogisticRegression()  # Using Logistic Regression for classification

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")
```

And the CSV file:
*name column just means the color of the lego-piece
*and the is_trans means is the lego piece translucent

```
id,name,is_trans
-1,Unknown,f
0,Black,f
1,Blue,f
2,Green,f
3,Dark Turquoise,f
4,Red,f
5,Dark Pink,f
6,Brown,f
7,Light Gray,f
8,Dark Gray,f
9,Light Blue,f
10,Bright Green,f
11,Light Turquoise,f
12,Salmon,f
13,Pink,f
14,Yellow,f
15,White,f
17,Light Green,f
18,Light Yellow,f
19,Tan,f
20,Light Violet,f
21,Glow In Dark Opaque,f
22,Purple,f
23,Dark Blue-Violet,f
25,Orange,f
26,Magenta,f
27,Lime,f
28,Dark Tan,f
29,Bright Pink,f
30,Medium Lavender,f
31,Lavender,f
32,Trans-Black IR Lens,t
33,Trans-Dark Blue,t
34,Trans-Green,t
35,Trans-Bright Green,t
36,Trans-Red,t
40,Trans-Black,t
41,Trans-Light Blue,t
42,Trans-Neon Green,t
43,Trans-Very Lt Blue,t
45,Trans-Dark Pink,t
46,Trans-Yellow,t
47,Trans-Clear,t
52,Trans-Purple,t
54,Trans-Neon Yellow,t
57,Trans-Neon Orange,t
60,Chrome Antique Brass,f
61,Chrome Blue,f
62,Chrome Green,f
63,Chrome Pink,f
64,Chrome Black,f
68,Very Light Orange,f
69,Light Purple,f
70,Reddish Brown,f
71,Light Bluish Gray,f
72,Dark Bluish Gray,f
73,Medium Blue,f
74,Medium Green,f
75,Speckle Black-Copper,f
76,Speckle DBGray-Silver,f
77,Light Pink,f
78,Light Flesh,f
79,Milky White,f
80,Metallic Silver,f
81,Metallic Green,f
82,Metallic Gold,f
84,Medium Dark Flesh,f
85,Dark Purple,f
86,Dark Flesh,f
89,Royal Blue,f
92,Flesh,f
100,Light Salmon,f
110,Violet,f
112,Blue-Violet,f
114,Glitter Trans-Dark Pink,t
115,Medium Lime,f
117,Glitter Trans-Clear,t
118,Aqua,f
120,Light Lime,f
125,Light Orange,f
129,Glitter Trans-Purple,t
132,Speckle Black-Silver,f
133,Speckle Black-Gold,f
134,Copper,f
135,Pearl Light Gray,f
137,Metal Blue,f
142,Pearl Light Gold,f
143,Trans-Medium Blue,t
148,Pearl Dark Gray,f
150,Pearl Very Light Gray,f
151,Very Light Bluish Gray,f
158,Yellowish Green,f
178,Flat Dark Gold,f
179,Flat Silver,f
182,Trans-Orange,t
183,Pearl White,f
191,Bright Light Orange,f
212,Bright Light Blue,f
216,Rust,f
226,Bright Light Yellow,f
230,Trans-Pink,t
232,Sky Blue,f
236,Trans-Light Purple,t
272,Dark Blue,f
288,Dark Green,f
294,Glow In Dark Trans,t
297,Pearl Gold,f
308,Dark Brown,f
313,Maersk Blue,f
320,Dark Red,f
321,Dark Azure,f
322,Medium Azure,f
323,Light Aqua,f
326,Olive Green,f
334,Chrome Gold,f
335,Sand Red,f
351,Medium Dark Pink,f
366,Earth Orange,f
373,Sand Purple,f
378,Sand Green,f
379,Sand Blue,f
383,Chrome Silver,f
450,Fabuland Brown,f
462,Medium Orange,f
484,Dark Orange,f
503,Very Light Gray,f
1000,Glow in Dark White,f
1001,Medium Violet,f
1002,Glitter Trans-Neon Green,t
1003,Glitter Trans-Light Blue,t
1004,Trans Flame Yellowish Orange,t
1005,Trans Fire Yellow,t
1006,Trans Light Royal Blue,t
1007,Reddish Lilac,f
9999,[No Color],f
```

dunno what to put here

Comment: Please post the full traceback message as a code block in the question. It makes it easier to spot the failing line.

Comment: this might be a stupid question but are you trying to predict the lego translucency from their names? If so, why? There is only a finite number of colours, you can use a dictionary for that

Comment: also this exists: https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Colour_Palette

Comment: I might be wrong but don't Machine Learning Models require numerical input for training? Have you tried converting your colors to numbers? (e.g. RGB value or something)?

Comment: `Here's the error:ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bright Green'` This seems very clear: `Bright Green` isn't a number. Logistic regression will only work with numbers. You will need to find a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the ML algorithms in sklearn, including Logistic Regression, expects it's `X_train` features to be numerical type. If you have any categorical data, like `color` feature in your case, you need to `one-hot-encode` them.
You can do that like below:

```
X_one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X, columns = ['name'])
```

You can get to know which columns to one-hot-encode by executing the following statement:

```
data.info()
```

All columns with type `object` are categorical, which might need encoding, again depending on the ML algorithm you choose.